# Where to put manually installed programs on Linux mint

Tags: directory-structure, linux-mint

I recently pulled a repo called ncspot and have the folder in my home/name directory. I was wondering where would be the best place to put this folder. Would it be best to put it in /usr/local? If not, where should I put it and why? Also I am on Linux Mint.

Linux file structure is still new to me and I am still learning, so any info or useful links are appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: This is off-topic for SO and surely discussed many times on more suitable sites, whether on the Stack Exchange network or not.

Comment: Where would be a better place to ask this? :)

Comment: @CalebRenfroe, this site is better place to ask this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/